# I don't succeed in passing information (object) using Ajax (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently struggling so as to pass information from my view to a controller (MVC model) in PHP. I am using the ajax method.

I would like to convey pieces of information such as strings or arrays to the controller:

```
            var dataToSend = [{ fieldname: 'ABC' }, { fieldname: 'DEF' }];
        dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'list': dataToSend });

        $(".application-accept").click(function(event){


            $.ajax({
                url: "/olad2/project/processapplication/1",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataToSend,
                datatype: "JSON",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log("done");
            }).fail(function(err){
                console.log(err.responseText);
                console.log("failed");


            });

        });
```

When I echo the result in the controller I have been told in error that there is no array:

```
echo json_encode(var_dump($_POST));
```

Which displays (console.log()):

```
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
```

*empty*
null

I know that there are a lot of topic about this subject but it doesn't work. Could you help me ?

ps: it is my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reviewed version works:

```js
$.ajax({
    url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
//  url: "/olad2/project/processapplication/1",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({list:[{ fieldname: 'ABC' }, { fieldname: 'DEF' }]}),
    datatype: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("done");
}).fail(function (err) {
    console.log(err.responseText);
    console.log("failed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But even your "almost unchanged" version would work with the typicode target address:

```js
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'list': [{ fieldname: 'ABC' }, { fieldname: 'DEF' }] });

$.ajax({
//  url: "/olad2/project/processapplication/1",
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  type: "POST",
  data: dataToSend,
  datatype: "JSON",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log("done");
}).fail(function(err) {
  console.log(err.responseText);
  console.log("failed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```